# SQLite sort order on datetime column populated from C# with DateTimeOffset

Tags: sqlite, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a Windows 8 Metro application that uses SQLite as its local database.

One of the tables in the database contains a datetime column. I'm seeing unexpected results when running queries that sort the resultset by the datetime column - the resultset isn't ordered how you would expect.

The datetime column is populated with data generated by the Metro application in C#; for example as `DateTimeOffset.Now`.  WinRT doesn't support `DateTime`, so we're using `DateTimeOffset`.

You can replicate this in a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Foo" ("DateOfFoo" DATETIME)
```

Here's some sample data based on data from our application (note that I'm in the PDT timezone which is UTC -7):

```
INSERT INTO "main"."Foo" ("DateOfFoo") VALUES (?1)
Parameters:
param 1 (text): 9/18/2012 8:08:56 AM -07:00

INSERT INTO "main"."Foo" ("DateOfFoo") VALUES (?1)
Parameters:
param 1 (text): 9/18/2012 8:13:42 AM -07:00

INSERT INTO "main"."Foo" ("DateOfFoo") VALUES (?1)
Parameters:
param 1 (text): 9/18/2012 12:46:36 PM -07:00
```

A simple query such as:

```
Select * From Foo Order By DateOfFoo
```

returns the following resultset:

```
9/18/2012 12:46:36 PM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:08:56 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:13:42 AM -07:00
```

when I would expect:

```
9/18/2012 8:08:56 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:13:42 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 12:46:36 PM -07:00
```

and `Select * From Foo Order By DateOfFoo DESC` returns:

```
9/18/2012 8:13:42 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:08:56 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 12:46:36 PM -07:00
```

when I would expect:

```
9/18/2012 12:46:36 PM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:13:42 AM -07:00
9/18/2012 8:08:56 AM -07:00
```

My colleague in the CDT timezone couldn't replicate the issue. I changed the time zone on my machine to CDT and populated the application data, and sure enough the query sorts the resultset correctly:

```
9/18/2012 2:46:36 PM -05:00
9/18/2012 10:13:42 AM -05:00
9/18/2012 10:08:56 AM -05:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support an actual date/time datatype. The dates and times are being inserted into the database as strings, and are therefore being sorted alphabetically on the `SELECT` statement. SQLite does support some date and time functions, but requires the strings to be in one of a list of formats, which the ones you are using do not match. For the proper formats, see the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Thanks glibdud. We're gonna work around this by sorting on the client instead of the query to SQLite.  In our case, a C# LINQ query.  We'll apply the OrderBy in C# after we get the data.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLite` stores date/time as strings. Assuming values are entered into your date/time field using a standard format you can use `orderby` with a custom `IComparer<string>`:

```
public class SqliteDateComparer : IComparer<string> {
  public int Compare(string s1, string s2) => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(s1), DateTime.Parse(s2));
}
```

and then ie:

```
var res = (new MyDbContext()).MyData.OrderBy(v => v.TimeField, new SqliteDateComparer());
```